# How to migrate manual proxy code from CRA to vite?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, vite

Im trying to migrate my CRA app to VITE. During the process, I have a proxy code which works in CRA. As explained here (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually). When i tried to recreate the same proxy code as explained in VITE docs, i'm getting the following errors.

1. Call to that proxy returns 500 error in networks tab
2. In localhost:5173 window, I have an error "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'req' in undefined"

Can someone assist me in successfully migrating this part of code. I've been stuck like this for a week now. Given below are the respective code files :

`setupProxy.js`

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const TARGET = 'https://devserverurl.com';

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: TARGET,
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
      onProxyReq: function (request, res) {
        request.setHeader('origin', TARGET);
      },
    })
  );

  app.get('/oidc-config', function (req, res, next) {
    const responseData = {
      client_id: import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENT_ID,
      redirect_uri: import.meta.env.VITE_REDIRECT_URI,
      response_type: import.meta.env.VITE_RESPONSE_TYPE,
      post_logout_redirect_uri: import.meta.env.VITE_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI,
      scope: import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENT_SCOPE,
      authority: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTHORITY,
      silent_redirect_uri: import.meta.env.VITE_SILENT_REDIRECT_URI,
      automaticSilentRenew: true,
      accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: import.meta.env.VITE_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRING_NOTIFICATION_TIME,
      mui_pro_license_key: import.meta.env.VITE_MUI_PRO_LICENSE_KEY,
    };
    res.send(responseData);
  });
};
```

`vite.config.ts`

```
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

const TARGET = 'https://devserverurl.com';

export default defineConfig({
  esbuild: {
    supported: {
      'top-level-await': true, 
    },
  },
  plugins: [react(), viteTsconfigPaths(), svgrPlugin()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: TARGET,
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        configure: (proxy, options) => {
          
          proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, res, options) => {
            proxyReq.setHeader('origin', TARGET);
          });
        },
      },
      '/oidc-config': {
        configure: (proxy, options) => {
          proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, res, options) => {
            const responseData = {
              client_id: process.env.VITE_CLIENT_ID,
              redirect_uri: process.env.VITE_REDIRECT_URI,
              response_type: process.env.VITE_RESPONSE_TYPE,
              post_logout_redirect_uri: process.env.VITE_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI,
              scope: process.env.VITE_CLIENT_SCOPE,
              authority: process.env.VITE_AUTHORITY,
              silent_redirect_uri: process.env.VITE_SILENT_REDIRECT_URI,
              automaticSilentRenew: true,
              accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: process.env.VITE_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRING_NOTIFICATION_TIME,
              mui_pro_license_key: process.env.VITE_MUI_PRO_LICENSE_KEY,
            };
          });
        },
      },
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['styled-components'],
    esbuildOptions: {
      define: {
        global: 'globalThis',
      },
      plugins: [
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          process: true,
          buffer: true,
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

[image: network tab]
[image: error]